# unable to access cassandra from azure data bricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, cassandra, databricks

whenever i am trying to access my cassandra cluster from azure databricks getting below error,

java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {xx.xx.xx.xx}:9142

Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /xx.xx.xx.xx:9142 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/xx.xx.xx.xx:9142] Cannot connect))

Cassandra was installed on azure vm ,both my azure vm & data bricks are in same VNET.

can you please someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running on Azure or AWS.. make sure to set broadcast_rpc_address to public IP address or dns hostname
these settings must work for you -

rpc_address: <**private ip of your vm** >

broadcast_rpc_address: <**public ip** or **hostname.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com**>

listen_address: **localhost**